# how to put code all on one line in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I'm new to programming on python 3 and was currently writing this program,

```
def checker(num):       

    if num >1:
       #check for factors 
       for I in range(2,num):
           if (num % I)== 0:
               print("%s is not a prime number.")
               print(I,"times",num//I,"is",num)
     else:
         print("%s is a prime number")

checker(1)

checker(2)

checker(3)


checker(4)

checker(5)
```

if I wanted for example to do the numbers all the way up to 1000, then is there any way to put all of the checker statements on one line or issue a command that would save me time and effort?

Comment: Sure, you could use a loop.

Comment: for i in range(1000):

Comment: You should put a break after `print(I,"times",num//I,"is",num)`

Comment: @Racialz: The OP would also need to fix the indent of the `else` (and its contents); they probably mean for it to match the `for` loop (and in that case, yes, the `break` is needed), but as written, it matches no prior indent. Might want to have an `else` case for the `if` too, so it prints something if passed `1`, `0`, `-1`, etc.

Comment: I really don't understand how you were able to use `for I in range(2,num):` in your function and are unable to use a loop like this anywhere else in your program.

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in range (1,1001):
    checker(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1000):
  checker(i+1)
```

This is a Python **for** loop.  This is a basic technique; you might consider reading ahead in your textbook (or whatever you're using to learn Python).  You could also delete this question.

Comment: That delete suggestion 

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
while i < 1001:
    checker(i)
    i+=1
```

Simple while loop with a way to stop it at 1000.
I will keep going up until it is no longer less that 1001 and breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Altough the answers to my question are helpful that it not what I asked, my function checker works fine. I just want to know how to put all of it onto one line.

anonymous_Hacker